# Replacing the contents or following text of a keyword in Powershell

Tags: powershell, random, text, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to replace the contents of a certain keyword or text in a .txt file
Example:

word.pass=haiwueuofbdkoabqo1738379

I want to replace the contents or text of word.pass=

I only know about replacing a certain keyword but not the following text or the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In it's simplest form you can look for a line that starts with `word.pass=` and replace the whole line:

```
$a = "word.pass=haiwueuofbdkoabqo1738379"
if ($a -like "word.pass=*") {
    $a = "word.pass=SomeNewText"
}
write-host $a
```

This answers the question you've posted, but I suspect that there's more to this.